# Springsource EBR is down. What next?

Tags: osgi-bundle, springsource, springsource-dm-server, eclipse-gemini

We proxied Springsource EBR in our own Nexus put a p2 capability on it so that we could use it in our p2 target platforms. Now since Springsource EBR is down the proxy doesn't work anymore. Now I got some questions:

1. Is there an alternative repository that contains all the bundles?
2. Did anyone else use Springsource EBR or am I the only one?
3. Would it make sense to build up a public EBR that contains all the bundles that have been hosted at Springsource? Maybe someone from Spring knows how much traffic has been on the EBR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... Eclipse initiated its own EBR project, which should be a clone and continuation of the former springsource EBR. Unluckily, this project seems to be dead :(
http://www.eclipse.org/ebr/ 
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/261/

As an alternative, you can try to use the Dependencies from the Apache Servicemix project, which are available at http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3Aorg.apache.servicemix.bundles

Comment: Hi Martin, I also stumbled upon the Eclipse EBR and I'm wondering why they don't put any effort into that. Meanwhile we took our proxied bundles and host them ourselves. As soon as we get new dependencies I will check out the servicemix bundles. Thanks for the hint. sebp